# How to go back to previous Collection visibility setting?

Tags: visibility, collections

Edit: Still a legitimate topic for 2.9.

- Let suppose that I have a complex visibility setting, with some collections visible and others invisible.
- If I want just one collection to be visible I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and click on the eye icon (*isolate*). Now only this specific collection is visible.
- But how can I quickly go back to my previous visibility setting? For the moment <kbd>ctrl</kbd> click brings back ALL the other collections visibility, not the previous setting where only some of the collections were visible. Is there a way to do it or do I have to click again on all the eye icons I want? A little bit tedious... but maybe I'm missing the simple solution ?

I start with this setting, collections 1 and 2 are invisible:

[image]

I just want to see collection 3 so I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click on collection 3:

[image]

I want my previous setting back (with collections 1 and 2 invisible), I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click on collection 3, but it brings all the collections back:

[image]

Comment: I've also been wondering if the 'Local View' has been discarded from 2.8 and now we should use the 'Hide from Viewport' buttons instead. They're not as handy in my mind.

Comment: I think Local View will be back like many other things